# DOM-Based cross-site scripting on window.location.pathname

Tags: xss, javascript

A scan with Burp has identified a DOM-Based cross-site scripting vulnerability.

The only script with a sink is the following.

Do you think it's a false positive? (Can I make it more secure in some way?)

```
var sPageURL = window.location.pathname;
var urlParts = sPageURL.split('/');
var page = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

var elem = $("a[href!=\\#]").filter(function () {
    //console.log(this.href + ' ' + this.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(page.toLowerCase()));
    return ((this.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(page.toLowerCase()) > 0) && (this.href.indexOf('#') < 0));
});
```

Then *elem* is used only to set a class on its parent, the following way:

```
elem.parent().addClass("active");
elem.parent().closest("li.treeview").addClass("active");
```

Comment: How does `elem` get used?

Comment: @Gray you're right, it's fundamental to define how it is used. I've added in the question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even if `page` could be whatever you want, its only use is to match other links on the page to add the `active` class.

The worst thing you could do would be setting all links in the page as active.

In my opinion, this doesn't count as a XSS vulnerability since no malicious code would be executed.